# How to parse duration strings in this format "hmmss", example "00047" into seconds using TimeSpan?

Tags: vb.net, parsing, timespan

Please how can we parse a simple duration string like "00047" into seconds using TimeSpan?

```
TimeSpan.ParseExact("00047", "hmmss", Nothing).TotalSeconds
```

The above gives errors:  "Input string was not in a correct format."

I'm parsing duration from call records

```
070615 1815 00047 9    9  806        00000000000       6103  807   80212  15  17           0     0                    
070615 1815 00155 7    9  806        00000000000       2206        41784      22           0     0                    
070615 1816 00249 7    9  806        00000000000       2206        41784      24           0     0
```

Is this an issue with TimeSpan.ParseExact?

If we are allowed to specify formats, e.g. **hmmss**, and we pass a string **00047** that maps directly to that format ...

What's the point of asking us for a format if you won't honor valid formats?

Comment: _What do the errors say?_

Comment: I have posted the error message, why the down votes?

Comment: @Plutonix i have added actual call logs. see the updated question please

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `h` format can be either one or two digits, so it will try to parse it as two digits and runs out of digits for the rest.

You can add a zero to the string and use the `hh` format:

```
TimeSpan.ParseExact("0" & "00047", "hhmmss", Nothing).TotalSeconds
```

Comment: thanks, but see the actual call logs. the format we receive is "hmmss"

Comment: @CharlesO: Yes, but it's not possible to parse that format as a `TimeSpan`. Get the value from the log, add a digit in front of it and parse it.

Comment: @CharlesO,  thats why he prepends a "0" to the value

Comment: i don't control the logs received. Is Padding with "0" is the only option?

Comment: @CharlesO you don't have to change anything in the logs, just use the statement that Guffa posted to parse the duration.

Comment: @CharlesO: It's the only option if you want to parse it as a `TimeSpan`. There are of course other ways, you could for example use `Substring` to get `"0"`, `"00"` and `"47"`, then parse each string to an integer, and then calculate how many seconds that is.

Comment: you are prepending to the value your code reads, not changing the logs: `TimeSpan.ParseExact("0" & strLogDuration, "hhmmss", Nothing).TotalSeconds` @CharlesO

Comment: @MattJohnson It is truly hmmss for example, 00234, also see updated question with sample logs. I am shocked that Timespan.ParseExact is throwing exceptions, hence my question

Comment: The key is in Guffa's first sentence.

Comment: @Plutonix is this an issue with the TimeSpan? IF we are allowed to specify a format - hmmss, and we pass a string 00047 why not honor the given format? What's the point of asking for a format if you won't honor a valid format?

Comment: @CharlesO: Without delimiters it's not possible to parse variable length components. For example formatting both `01:23:00` and `12:03:00` using the format `"hm"` both produce the string `"123"`, so it's not possible to determine which meaning the string would have when you parse it. If you have a format like `"0-0047"` then you could parse that using `"h\-mmss"` because the delimiter allows the parser to determine how many digits `h` should use.

Comment: A TimeSpan format string of "h" just means that `9:12` wont display as "09:12".  You would not want `11:42` to display as "1:42" would you?  The format strings are not free form affairs.  see [Custom TimeSpan Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287(v=vs.110).aspx)  where for `"h"` it says `Single-digit hours do not have a leading zero.`

Comment: @Guffa I don't agree. I specify a format that maps exactly to an input and it fails :) ... come on

Comment: @CharlesO: The problem is with the "exactly". The format specifier `h` doesn't have an exact format, it can be either one or two digits. There is no format specifier for a single digit hour component.

Comment: @Plutonix Exactly, you enforce my point. see Custom TimeSpan Format Strings where for "h" it says Single-digit hours do not have a leading zero.

Comment: No leading zero doesnt rule out the possibility of a 2 digit hour, it just means it wont *show* a leading zero in output (it wont show `11` as `1` either).  Guffa has explained it better; I'd trust his gold badges in VB, C# and .NET.

Comment: sigh, i don't understand it, but if this is the only way to do this with TimeSpan..., then i guess this is the answer i have to accept.

Comment: The string is parsed from left to right. Since there are no delimiters, parsing `"12345"` with `"hmmss"`, the `h` format allows for one or two digits, so the hours would be read as `12`, then `mm` would be `34`, leaving only a single digit of `5` left for `ss`.  Since `ss` requires two digits, you get the error.    If instead it parsed from right to left, you would not have this problem - but that is not the behavior of this particular method.